# Phone freezes when i recording phone call in wav format with audio recoder

Tags: android, audio-recording, file-handling

This is code  Which i used for recording phone call. I am also using async task but when my file got recorded  phone freezes. Recording  the call and save file in external storage and then copy that file from storage and uploaded to url fot transaltion , that the procedure i use but my screen freezes in this purpose. Can anyone help me out from this problem

```
 public class WavRecorder extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void> {
private static final String TAG = "--DEBUG---";
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";

FileOutputStream os = null;
int bufferSize;
int frequency = 44100; //8000;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
boolean started = false;

short threshold = 15000;
int noisetime = 1500;

Handler hd;
AudioRecord audioRecord;

private OnRecorderresponse mListener;

public interface OnRecorderresponse {
    public void OnAudioFileSaved(String FilePath);
    public void OnSpeechToTextRecognized(String Text);
}

public WavRecorder(OnRecorderresponse listener)
{
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public void setStarted(boolean started) {
    this.started = started;

    hd = new Handler();

}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Looper.prepare();

    Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground");
    try {

        final String filename = getTempFilename();

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
        Log.e("Buffersize",""+bufferSize);

        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

        Log.e("Buffersize",""+audioRecord);

        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    Log.e("Running","yes");
                copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
                deleteTempFile();
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Check for file :: "+filename);
                    os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        while (started) {
            int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != bufferReadResult) {
                //check signal
                //put a threshold
                int foundPeak = searchThreshold(buffer, threshold);

                byte[] byteBuffer = ShortToByte(buffer, bufferReadResult);
                try {
                    os.write(byteBuffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (foundPeak > -1) { //found signal

                    //record signal
                    hd.removeCallbacks(sendData);
                    hd.postDelayed(sendData, noisetime);

                } else {//count the time
                    //don't save signal

                }
                Log.e(TAG, "foundPeak");
            }
        }

        audioRecord.stop();
        Log.e(TAG, "Stoped");
        //close file
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
        deleteTempFile();


    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
    }

    return null;



}

byte[] ShortToByte(short[] input, int elements) {
    int short_index, byte_index;
    int iterations = elements; //input.length;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[iterations * 2];

    short_index = byte_index = 0;

    for (/*NOP*/; short_index != iterations; /*NOP*/) {
        buffer[byte_index] = (byte) (input[short_index] & 0x00FF);
        buffer[byte_index + 1] = (byte) ((input[short_index] & 0xFF00) >> 8);

        ++short_index;
        byte_index += 2;
    }

    return buffer;
}



int searchThreshold(short[] arr, short thr) {
    int peakIndex;
    int arrLen = arr.length;
    for (peakIndex = 0; peakIndex < arrLen; peakIndex++) {
        if ((arr[peakIndex] >= thr) || (arr[peakIndex] <= -thr)) {
            //se supera la soglia, esci e ritorna peakindex-mezzo kernel.

            return peakIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1; //not found
}


private String getFilename() {

    Log.e("Tag", "Entered in  getfilename");

    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.e("Tag","File is not exist,make dirs");
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}


private String getTempFilename() {

    Log.e("Tag", "Entered in gettempfilename");

    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    Log.e("gettempfilename",""+file);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}


private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());

    file.delete();
}


private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, final String outFilename) {

    Log.e("Tag", "Enteredin copywavefile");

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = frequency;
    int channels = 1;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * frequency * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;


        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

        // callback
        mListener.OnAudioFileSaved(outFilename);
        Log.e("ouitputfilename", outFilename);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {

    Log.e("Tag","Entered in WriteWaveFileHeader");

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (channels * 16 / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
}
```

Comment: not sure without any log/stacktrace but in your sendData Runnable you are opening a ressource without closing it. So each time the thread is started you are leaking memory and ressource. You may want to use the java 7 try with ressource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: How can i resolve this, how can i close the resource from my code can u  help me

Comment: I gave you an hint in my comment.

Comment: See the copywavefile method already close the  resources, that is used in senddata runnable

Comment: No in the sendData you change reference and old one is not closed. Read an introduction to java file and resources.

Comment: it will  not work i will close all the resources